# Создание папок под объекты microsoft management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

Можно ли в microsoft management studio самостоятельно создавать собственные папки под объекты и туда складывать объекты?

Если нет, то есть ли какие-нибудь плагины?

**UPD**

Речь идет не о группировке объектов БД по папкам в файловой системе, а создание папок в интерфейсе microsoft management studio.

Например, есть БД есть 100 таблиц, я создал 10 папок и по ним распихал таблицы.

Answer (score 3):

Такой возможности не предусмотрено. Насчет плагинов не знаю, но обычно плагины для management studio используют базовые возможности студии и следовательно такой возможности тоже не смогут предоставить.

Comment: Я что-то нашел, но оно платно http://www.skilledsoftware.com/ , хотелось бы что-нибудь бесплатное...

Comment: Вообще для группировки объектов есть схемы, и стандартный фильтр в студии под это заточен.

Comment: @Lavel - я бы оформил комментарий как ответ (сам хотел предложить схемы+фильтр).

Answer (score 0):

Именно из плагинов к SSMS с требуемым функционалом есть [SQLTreeo](http://www.sqltreeo.com/page/download) - он дешевле чем  skilledsoftware.com (подробный список плагинов можно найти [здесь](https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/blob/master/SSMS/SSMS_Addins.md)). Также можете посмотреть на [альтернативы SSMS](http://sqlserver-kit.org/en/sql-server-utilities?queries%5Bsearch%5D=%5BMS%5D)